# SaveAs function extremely Slow

Tags: excel, vba, performance, optimization, save-as

I have a fairly simple loop that copies data from a few locations, creates a new worksheet with it, creates a workbook from that sheet, saves it, and deletes it.

Sometimes this loop runs nearly instantly and I can save 20ish files in about 5 seconds, however sometimes it will take 15 to 20 seconds to finish each iteration of this loop, which causes it to take several minutes unexpectedly. I haven't been able to find any outside source (tried with all other programs closed) that seems to slow it down. I've also done the typical methods of speeding up the loop like disabling screen updating and calculations.

I don't know if there is a more efficient way to loop this process, but I've verified this section in particular is the part that causes the delays as placing breaks while debugging has shown the differences in time and the other sections are all nearly instant. The section below is slightly modified to remove code that is known not to be problematic.

Edit - Additionally, I should mention each of these sheets are extremely small, holding only around 10 rows and 2 columns of data.

```
for i = 1 to 100
        featureSheet.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\DIR\" & HeaderFile.Sheets("SheetName").Range("C" & i).Value & ".json", FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        featureSheet.Delete
Next i
```

Comment: I guess, copying and deleting sheet 100 times makes it slower...
how does it perform without `featureSheet.Copy` / `featureSheet.delete` ?

Comment: @RolandasKol Well unfortunately that is the only convenient way I've found to collect this. Since I need to save 100 (Making up number there but that's close) files from the data I gather, each sheet will need to be saved individually. The best way I've found to save a sheet (not the whole book) is simply to make that sheet a separate book and save it.

Comment: what if you move them, instead of copying, - so you will get rid of one step `.delete`

Comment: I don't believe moving the sheet accomplishes what is needed. If I have 10 sheets and need to save one, I copy that specific worksheet out of the book, so I then have a workbook of one sheet, which I can then save to the format described in SaveAs. After that data is used, I then close that workbook and remove that worksheet from my workbook, so that at the end I don't have an additional 100 worksheets.

Comment: not sure if you understood, simple `featureSheet.Move` will create new workbook and remove sheet from the main workbook.
So `featureSheet.Delete` will not be necesery

Comment: and of course... I hope you use all that jazz below:
`Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False`

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know that was a function! Sorry for that. I implemented that change and it did help by about 20%! It still seems like the SaveAs function is taking the largest chunk but this is a definite improvement.

Comment: I would sugest to make a separate Module, call it StopPr and place all these:
`Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False`
And use `Call StopPr ` at the start of each macros you create...
For the end, create StartPr Module with `True` values, - and call it at the end of each macros you have.